# Calendar in jsp

Tags: jsp

i am trying for a jsp caledar.It will be with out pop-up.I am trying a lot but i didnt get that.And i want monthly navigation in that form.Means it increases by 1 month.If you have some source code in jsp than plz send it to me.Hope you will give reply.Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). A "JSP calendar" in the end would still be a combination of HTML and Javascript being generated by JSP, so I'd suggest using something that's pure HTML & JS, has been used a lot by many people and is therefore pretty well tested.